# How to fix the `Argument missing for parameter - Pylance reportCallIssue` issue for Python decorator of method?

Tags: python, mypy, python-decorators, python-typing, pyright

I have a decorator which works at run time, but the Pylance report `Argument missing for parameter - Pylance "arg" reportCallIssue`, how can I fix it?

### environment

- Python 3.10
- Pylance at VSCode

### the code

```py
import functools
from typing import Any, Callable


def decorator(func: Callable[[Any, str], str]):
    """Intention:

    a decorator for a method which takes one string argument after the self and returns a string
    """

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def display_and_return_the_result(self, arg: str) -> str:
        result = func(self, arg)
        print(result)
        return result

    return display_and_return_the_result


class MyClass:
    @decorator
    def method(self, name: str) -> str:
        return f"Hello {name}!"
```

### run

run with no error

```bash
-> Hello world!
```

### Screenshot

[image]

I want to change some code and report no error, but do not know what to do?

### More

I have applied the fix from @STerliakov's comments, and the code becomes

```py
import functools
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

_S = TypeVar("_S", bound="MyClass")


def decorator(func: Callable[[_S, str], str]) -> Callable[[_S, str], str]:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def display_and_return_the_result(self: _S, arg: str) -> str:
        result = func(self, arg)
        print(result)
        return result

    return display_and_return_the_result


class MyClass:
    @decorator
    def method(self, name: str) -> str:
        return f"Hello {name}!"


c = MyClass()
c.method("world")
```

This code can pass Pylance check, however, there are still errors if I use a keyword argument

[image]

is that possible to support both positional and keyword argument?

Comment: You're missing return type annotation, and so pyright has to guess and does that incorrectly. Just add a return type annotation - a good habit is actually to never omit them.

Comment: https://pyright-play.net/?code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMIQDYGcCwAUAlBCHDAJ5jAoDmcokscAwgIbbbsBG2ApgBo4AFWr8AauyhEA%2BgGU4AXlHipUABQAiBVuE8IqACZKtAWUqtuuXFoCURIkf4I4ztNHaZNydAC42Tm4%2BfgBtUIVhXBgoAF0omNi7OABaAD5Arl4BcMi4aLiEuL8iODK4AAFfDCw8ADoAdyh2MFwNaodCcrcXN2BcMG5KWXYUI1kofhgkKBRZGAALfgn%2BXCRsGA1cfmwEALzpOgCC5PT8mJKu7vLJtY3lRFQ0LZ2EYUPO6-KwKFpN2-WME%2BXzgk2ms1Bq0BjiuZTBMxQfQGQxGYxW4Lmi2WAI2MLQ1lwcAsVnYNku3Qq7k83lK5WcrhAUwWECML12whQ7EZxxipwyBXJIPhEIQWgAEjtsBA4ABvTmMgC%2BAEItEQgA

Comment: There are still issue, and I have put it in end of the questions

Comment: Missed this comment - yes, it's possible, but you need to replace `Callable` with a custom protocol or use a ParamSpec with `*args, **kwargs` instead of specifying a single argument. I'll write an answer with examples of both today.

Comment: I have figured out how to use *args, **kwargs, but I have no idea of the custom protocol. I would appreciate it if you could give me a hint on how to approach that^^